# Why does PDFRenderer creates black borders?

Tags: android, pdfrenderer

I try to generate a bitmap from this [PDF file](https://jumpshare.com/v/QmhugHRAsJ5y5dUX8vT1).
My code is the following one:

```
    mFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
    if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
        mPdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(mFileDescriptor);
    }

    if (mPdfRenderer != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < mPdfRenderer.getPageCount(); i++) {
            printPage(i);
        }
    }

....

private void printPage(int index) {
    byte[] img;
    if (mPdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
        return;
    }
    // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
    if (null != mCurrentPage) {
        mCurrentPage.close();
    }
    // Use `openPage` to open a specific page in PDF.
    mCurrentPage = mPdfRenderer.openPage(index);


    int width = (int)(203.0 / 72.0 * mCurrentPage.getWidth() + 0.5);
    int height = (int)(203.0 / 72.0 * mCurrentPage.getHeight() + 0.5);
    // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT);

    try {
        sendImageToPrinter(PrinterEventsProto.Image.parseFrom(bitmap), getApplicationContext());
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the correspdonding bitmap is this one where I don't understand where this black border comes from. Any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your width and height of your bitmap do not match the width and height of the screen (the activity window).

Don't set your bitmap height and width to arbitrary values like you're doing here: `int width = (int)(203.0 / 72.0 * mCurrentPage.getWidth() + 0.5)`

You could try setting the width of the bitmap to `mCurrentPage.getWidth()` and the height to `mCurrentPage.getHeight()`. Then, if you set the scale type of the ImageView that you're displaying to fit, it should display to the full page width and height.

Or if you're sending it to a printer, it should print the full page and not cut anything off. Although, you may need to change the height and width of the bitmap to fit on the type of paper you're printing. In that instance, use this info to produce a properly scaled bitmap for A4 paper:

> 8.27" x 11.69" Equivalent A4 paper dimensions in pixels at 300 DPI and 72 DPI respectively are: 2480 pixels x 3508 pixels (print resolution)
>   595 pixels x 842 pixels (screen resolution)
>   http://www.graphic-design-employment.com/a4-paper-dimensions.html